# Why do I have to turn off the Firewall in Windows-7 to print to my wireless printer?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I cannot print to my wireless printer unless firewall is turned off in windows-7.

This printer works fine from other computers connected to my wireless network.  I thought that it used to work from this laptop also but NOT now and I have no idea why it quit working.

I know that it is the firewall because I can turn it off and the printer works fine from this computer.  Only fails if I have the firewall engaged.

Comment: What firewall software, or the embedded Windows firewall? Either way you probably just javelin to create a rule,  the printer software usually does that for you automatically, sounds like something removed or disabled the rule.

Comment: Please specify the exact model of printer you have and who it was manufactured by.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your system, why type of firewall and virus protection you are using... how many computers... static IP or DHCP.... check your firewall incoming rules. Firewall -> Advanced -> Incoming & Outgoing, and make sure you don't have the printer's IP blocked.

Comment: Printer = Epson Artisan 835

Comment: Microsoft Windows 7 firewall.  Embedded windows firewall?  Don't know what that is.  I have two systems using windows 10.  One is cable connected to the wireless router the other connects wireless.  Both connect to the printer wireless.  Both print just fine, as does the problem computer AFTER I HAVE DISABLED THE "home or work(private) network location settings"

Comment: I am using Malwarebytes.  That has been removed and I removed and reloaded the printer driver software.

Comment: I installed a program called "Tiny Wall" to my system.  after I re-installed windows 7.  I then attempted to install the epson drivers and software but it failed to complete the install.  It failed the part where you can select Auto (installation of the IP address of the printer) and it also failed when I selected the manual installation.  I had previously ran the Network Status/Check Network Connection for the printer and therefor had all that information on hand.  Then I selected MODE CHANGE in TINY WALL, and the printer completed the installation and printed the test page.

Comment: So, does anyone know how to edit the "OUTGOING" portion of windows 7 firewall?

Comment: I forgot to list the "MODE CHANGE" that I implemented in "TINY WALL" the mode I implemented was "allow outgoing."  When I reset the mode to "normal operation," the wireless printer fails to print again.

Comment: Come on, there has to be a WIZARD out there somewhere that knows how to fix this.

Comment: Okay something else I forgot to mention.  When I power up my laptop I get this msg about Epson Mgr.

Comment: windows security alert. / Windows firewall has blocked some features of this program.  /  Windows Firewall has blocked some features of EEventManager Application on all private networks.  //  Name: EEventManager Application  //  Publisher:  /SEIKO EPSON CORPORATION  //  Path:  (of program in my system)  ///  Allow EEventManager Application to communicate on these networks:  ///  Private networks, such as my home or work network  ///  Allow access or Cancel

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this problem. It only took me six days of pretty steady work. So here is the answer.

I am not sure if this is necessary or not but I left the homegroup first. Then proceeded with this routine.

Open a cmd prompt by clicking on start, type in "cmd prompt" (without the quotation marks) right click on "cmd prompt" at the top of the window and select "Run as Administrator" when command prompt is open type in "secpol" and press enter key. WAIT FOR IT! "Local Security Policy" window should open. (it did on my windows 7 on Toshiba laptop.) Search down left hand list until you find "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" Click on the little arrow on the left of the listing and expand it showing "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security - Local Group Policy Listing" click on that listing and your profile overview will appear in the right hand column. At the bottom of the list, domain, private, and public profiles, you will see "Windows Firewall Properties" listed in BLUE.  Click on that start with the Domain Profile. Set firewall state to "ON", set inbound connections to "Block" default. Set outbound connections to "Allow" default. Now change to the Private Profile tab at the top of the window and make the same changes as you did for the Domain Profile.  Then change to the Public Profile and make the same changes as you did for the other two profiles.  Then select IPsec Settings, click on "customize" to the right of IPsec defaults and set all to the default setting, click Okay.  click on "not configured" to the right of IPsec exemptions Exempt ICMP from IPsec: and change to "No" default.  Now at IPsec tunnel authorization select "NO" click "apply" then click "OK".  Now you should see that all profiles are set "ON" green check, "block inbound" red IBSM, "Allow Outbound" green check. Close that window, close the command prompt by typing "exit" and enter.  You should now be able to print to your wireless printer.